# Combine Multiple Columns of Data into Two Columns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have several sheets of poll data that are structured in this manner:

`ID|Name|Email|Date|Q1|A1|Q2|A2|Qx|Ax`

I'd like to combine all of the Qs into one column and the As in the one next to it while maintaining the data of the submitter.

I found this on Exceltip but it only transposes the header row rather than the data rows.

```
Sub MultipleColumns2SingleColumn()

 Const shName1 As String = "Sheet1"       'Change sheet name here

 Const shName2 As String = "Sheet2"

 Dim arr, arrNames

 With Worksheets(shName1)

    arrNames = .Range("F1", .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))

    For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        arr = .Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 4)

        With Worksheets(shName2)

            With .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)

                .Offset(1).Resize(UBound(arrNames, 2), 4) = arr

                .Offset(1, 5).Resize(UBound(arrNames, 2)) = Application.Transpose(arrNames)

            End With

        End With

    Next

 End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple unpivot operation, easily done in Power Query (available in Excel 2010+)

- In Excel 2016+ (it's different in the earlier versions), with your cursor in your data table: `Data/Get&Transform/From Table/Range`
- In the Power Query UI:

  - Select the columns you wish to retain
  - then `Unpivot other columns`

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Name", type text}, {"Email", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Q1", type text}, {"A1", type text}, {"Q2", type text}, {"A2", type text}, {"Q3", type text}, {"A3", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"ID", "Name", "Email", "Date"}, "Attribute", "Value")
in
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns"
```

[image]